# How to end a method in a class if user input is blank

Tags: python, class, return

I'm new to programming so bear with me please! 
I'm creating a class and having trouble getting the return message to show when the users input is empty.
Instead of returning my message it's just throwing me an error.

I want my code to return "please try again" and end, if the user input is blank.

Code:

```
class BankAccount():

    def __init__(self):
        # asking for a name
        self.name = str(input("Hello! Welcome to the Bank of Alex.\nWhat is your name?"))
        if self.name == "":
            return "please try again"
        else:
            print(f"\nWelcome, {self.name.title()}.")
```

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 account = BankAccount()

TypeError: **init**() should return None, not 'str

Comment: `__init__` is not what you are thinking of. You probably meant to write a `__main__` function. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this with help from @Prune.  I used the while loop he mentioned and put it under __ init __

So if user input is blank it will just keep prompting for an input.  Not a perfect solution but it works.

```
class BankAccount():

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = input("Hello! Welcome to the Bank.\nWhat is your name?")
        while self.name == "":
            self.name = input("Please enter your name")
        if self.name:
            print(f"\nWelcome, {self.name.title()}.")
```

Answer (score 5):

Your program structure is incorrect for using a class.  You should not create an object until you know the input is valid.  Have the calling program check it:

```
name = ""
while name == "":
    name = input("Enter your name")
    if name:
        acct = BankAccount(name)
        break
    else:
        print("Please try again")
```

Your `__init__` method then merely crates the account -- no name check.  This method implicitly returns the created object; you're not allowed to return anything else.

Comment: Such a nice and polite way to say "don't do it"

Comment: @Evgeny: nah -- it's just showing how we've learned to partition our functionality over the past half-century or so.  In this case, it's merely waiting: don't go to the trouble of creating a new object until we have all the required parameters nailed down.

Comment: Thanks! that worked but now it's throwing me a new error message

TypeError: BankAccount() takes no arguments

I tried using BankAccount(self) and BankAccount(name) and that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: You'll need to adjust your class so that `__init__` takes the provided name as a parameter: `def __init__(self, name): ...`